# how to use command line to start celery when I install it both in python2,python3

Tags: python, celery

I used celery + requests first in python2.7,and it works fine,but I heard celery + aiohttp is faster,so I test it in python3, and it really fast,but then I found I can't use celery to start my program write in python2.7,because there are changes between them ,I use command line to start celery only get errors
I guess I should just uninstall the celery of python3?
Is there a better way to do this?
In fact,I guess since there are many package works for both p2,p3,and use commandline to start,there must have a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a virtual environment. A virtual environment encapsulates a Python install, along with all the pip packages And executable files such as celery. check out the virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper Python packages.

Comment: I knew virtualenv,but never take it serious,today I learned a lesson,and it works,thank you